# Show that a harmonic function satisfying given condition is even

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $u$ be harmonic on a neighborhood of the origin, and suppose $u$ is zero on the real and imaginary axes.  Show $u$ is even.

I don't know where to start, would someone please give me a hint?

Comment: Schwarz Reflection...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, you need to use Schwarz reflection principle (applied to harmonic functions). Since your function $u$ is defined on the intersection of a neighborhood of the origin and the upper half plane and vanishes on the real axis, you can extend it harmonically on an open set in the lower half by $\tilde{u}(x,y)=-u(x,-y)$. Since $\tilde{u}$ and $u$ coincide on an open set in the UHP it must be $\tilde{u}=u$.

Now repeat for the imaginary axis and draw the conclusions.